# What is Python looking for when it tries to "import"?

Tags: python, windows

Imagine some hypothetical python code:

```
from turboencabulator import panametricfan
```

If i try to run this on my computer (Windows, 64-bit, Windows 10), it fails to find the [`turboencabulator`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ac7G7xOG2Ag) module:

[image]

### What is it looking for?

When Python is attempting to load a module, what is it looking for? Is it a `.py` file? Is it a `.dll` (since this is Windows). Is it a folder?

### Windows has modules; they're called *assemblies*

Windows has the notion of *assemblies*. If you declare you want to use an assembly called `turboencabulator`, it will look for an *assembly manifest*:

- turboencabulator.manifest

You can also create a **folder** called `turboencabulator`, where it will look for an assemebly manifest there:

```
turboencabulator
|--- turboencabulator.manifest
```

That manifest will then in turn declare all the files that make up that assembly.

For example, if i need to use the **Microsoft Visual C Runtime 8.0**, i would declare a dependency on the module

> Microsoft.VC80.CRT

Then Windows will go hunting for:

1. **`Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest`** file in the folder
2. **`Microsoft.VC80.CRT`** folder

   - which then must contain `Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest`
3. Some other places (like `WinSxS`, maybe the path, who knows)

And then the manifest is simply a text file that lets you know that **msvcrt** is comprised of 3 dlls:

- `<file name="msvcr80.dll" />`
- `<file name="msvcp80.dll" />`
- `<file name="msvcm80.dll" />`

### What is python looking for?

When i specify i want to import a module:

```
from RetroEncabulator import GirdleSpring
```

**what** is python looking for?

- a binary?
- a zip?
- is it a named item that has been registered in the registry?
- the name of a module manifest file that declares all the files that make up the module?

**What**, exactly, is python looking for?

### Bonus Questions

- where does it look
- can it be configured to look places
- can modules be *registered* somewhere, so it doesn't *have* to go hunting? (as correctly written Windows applications are supposed to do)

### Bonus Chatter

- in reality i'm `from numpy`
- in reality i'm `from cntk`

And neither of these *"things"* are *"found"*.

### Bonus Reading

- [Python - Modules](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm)

### Additional Investigation

To contrast the heresay so far, i decided to actually spy on python to see what it goes and looks for:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Python/PythonCore/2.7/Modules/turboencabulator
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Python/PythonCore/2.7/Modules/turboencabulator
- D:\DevelopPy\Bunny\turboencabulator
- D:\DevelopPy\Bunny\turboencabulator.pyd
- D:\DevelopPy\Bunny\turboencabulator.py
- D:\DevelopPy\Bunny\turboencabulator.pyw
- D:\DevelopPy\Bunny\turboencabulator.pyc
- D:\Programs\Python27\DLLs\turboencabulator
- D:\Programs\Python27\Lib\turboencabulator
- D:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\turboencabulator

I see it looking in the registry. Does that mean it can be registered?
I see it looking for files besides `py` (`pyc`, `pyw`, `pyd`). Are those compiled?
I see it looking in the `Python\DLLs` folder. Does that means that there can be DLLs?
I see it looking in `Lib`? Are those for intermediate object binaries?

Man, it really has been four years without being able to figure it out. Sure would be super if the SO community was helpful. Well-earned reputation.

Comment: Guessing this is gonna be self-answered? Regardless: is the question Windows-specific?

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose of this rambling question is. The link at the end seems to go to exactly the kind of tutorial it seems to be asking for, but Stack Overflow isn't a place to ask for links to tutorials in the first place.

Comment: @Blckknght The page doesn't indicate what kind of file python goes looking for. It doesn't indicate if it even goes **looking** for a file.

Comment: @user2864740 The question *might* be Windows specific. I assume all modules in python are actually `dll` files? And if it's done correctly, these python dll modules are registered. (which are concepts i assume Linux doesn't have)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem

Comment: No why would you assume that? Have you done any basic Python tutorial? Any python file is a module.

Comment: @DanielRoseman a) because this is Windows b) Windows already has canonical method of presenting modules c) i don't know any differently

Comment: But *your own link* tells you that. What was the point of posting it without reading it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you quote for me where it tells me that? Even better, put it in the form of an answer. I **could** dig out **Process Monitor** and filter for someone looking for objects (files, folders, registry keys) called `turboencabulator`. But getting an actual answer would be super.

Comment: Second paragraph: "Simply, a module is a file consisting of Python code."

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hmmm, which contradicts what the only answer so far says. Either way, **what** does it look for? [This other link on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem) say it looks for somthing called `__init__.py`. Perhaps it looks for `__turboencabulator__.py`?

Comment: Third paragraph: "The Python code for a module named `aname` normally resides in a file named `aname.py`."

Comment: Using the  Microsoft Visual C Runtime isn't a good example. See Python's [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#module-msvcrt) module.

Comment: @martineau I wasn't implying that python uses msvcrt. I was showing an example of how other systems on Windows stores and locate modules. The idea then would be to contrast it with how **python** stores and locates modules. Other examples on Windows would be COM class registration by ProgID, and CLR assemblies signed, placed in the GAC, and located by their signed hash. Because in the end when python cannot find `numpy`, i have no place to start to figure out where its looking, or what it's looking for, so i can diagnose it.

Answer (score 1):

When you include `import` statement in your code, python tries to find the **python file** or **package directory** with `__init__.py` file in it the following order

1. current working directory
2. local user site packages
3. common site packages

You can see the path by the following code

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

You can also add your own path.

**Note:** You must add this line before importing other modules

```
import sys
sys.path.append("your/complete/path/to/directory")
```

Comment: What **python file** does it go looking for? Does it look for `turboencabulator.py`? What **package directory** does it go looking for? Does it look for `turboencabulator`? Does this mean that modules in python are not compiled binaries?

Comment: have you seen the output of sys.path ?